# Jsoup display data to textview

Tags: java, android, parsing, textview, jsoup

I parsed a html web page with jsoup. now i want to display my parsed data in my textview.

**code**

```
    String ID = loginpreferences.getString("ID", null);
    String Type = loginpreferences.getString("Type", null);

    String myURL = "http://roosters.gepro-osi.nl/roosters/rooster.php?leerling="+ID+"&type=Leerlingrooster&afdeling="+Type+"&tabblad=2&school=905";



        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(myURL).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Elements data = doc.select(".1nameheader");




}    
}
```

**I tried**

```
Textview1.SetText(data);
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean "didn't work?" Nothing displayed? Error Message?

Comment: data is not a String. You need to get the text out of the list of elements.

Comment: it is not possible to do .SetText at all: But how do i get the text out of the list of elements?

Answer (score 1):

Seems as if you want to print the text values from a list of Elements. To do so you need to iterate over the list of Elements and get the text out of them.

```
   StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
   for(Element e: data){
       text.append(e.text());
   }
   Textview1.setText(text.toString());
```

Comment: i use       Document doc = Jsoup.parse(myURL);
            Elements links = doc.select(".1nameheader");
            String tekst = links.text().toString();
      
            textView1.setText(tekst);               but it doesn't display anything.

Comment: Are you sure that .1nameheader selector returns elements from your page?

Answer (score 0):

Line

```
Textview1.SetText(data);
```

shouldn't even compile.

From [Android TextView class reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html):

```
final void   setText(CharSequence text)
             Sets the string value of the TextView.
```

You're giving `Elements` class instance to the method.

`Element` and `Elements` classes of `JSoup` provide you with `html()` and `text()` methods that you should use in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried android.text.html.forHtml(String)?
This method gets a html as input and returns a spanned text that you cat set it to a TextView