# Jsoup element text to textview

Tags: java, android, parsing, jsoup

I want to display my element to an textview.

**code**

```
   Document doc = Jsoup.parse(myURL);
   Elements name  = doc.getElementsByClass(".lNameHeader");
   for (Element nametext : name){
       String text = nametext.text();

       tabel1.setText(text);
```

but it displays nothing.

(the site i am parsing http://roosters.gepro-osi.nl/roosters/rooster.php?leerling=120777&type=Leerlingrooster&afdeling=12-13_OVERIG&tabblad=2&school=905)

Comment: Don't see any styling on that page using `1nameheader`?

Comment: sorry it have to be `.lnameheader` but it still doesen't display anything

Comment: How do i select the nameheaderthing? because i thought lnameheader was the class for it.

Comment: It still doesn't work. i think i did something wrong with jsoup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011029/jsoup-display-data-to-textview) it shows that `myURL` is a `String`. In this case you are are using the constructor [Jsoup.parse(String html)](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29).

You need the one that takes a `URL` to make the connection:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new URL(myURL), 2000);
Elements name = doc.getElementsByClass("lNameHeader");
```

Also drop the leading `.` character from the class name. If you don't wish to specify a timeout you can simply use:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(myURL).get();
```

Comment: okay this works on my emulator. but when i try it on my phone. it force closes at the parse. ?

Comment: Do you have [internet access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206822/no-internet-on-android-emulator-why-and-how-to-fix) allowed on your phone?

Comment: yes. i figured out, i needed to start a new thread for android 3.0 or higher. otherwise it would force close

Answer (score 1):

Actually the class for it is:

```
lNameHeader
```

Note that first letter is not 1 (one) - it's l (letter L)

So it should be:

```
Elements name  = doc.getElementsByClass("lNameHeader");
```

Note also that JSoup `getElementsByClass` methods doesn't work like CSS selectors - so the `.` must be omitted.

Comment: Oh! Sorry @Georggroenendaal - didn't noticed it - updated my answer.